# Alternative ways of finding the least possible value of $|x+y+z|$

Tags: optimization, alternative-proof

Assume

$$ 6 \leq |x| \leq 8 $$

$$1 \leq |y| \leq 2 $$

$$ 3 \leq |z| \leq 4$$

The trick is to consider the negative values the three unknowns can take.

If $x,y,z$, satisfy the equalities shown, what is the least possible value of $|x+y+z|$?

I can solve this problem via brute force, trying all cases, and I obtain the answer of zero.

Is there a geometric or more slick or intuitive way of solving this problem that is faster than the brute force method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would note first that the "width" of the system is $2+1+1=4$, so for any particular choice of signs (and there are eight such) the values of $|\pm x\pm y\pm z|$ lie in an interval of width $4$ - the constraints are inclusive, so the intervals are closed.

The central values are $7, 1.5, 3.5$ and you want to get as close to zero as possible. A greedy algorithm (largest value first and choose the sign which gets you closest to zero for in size order) seems to do the job.

$7-3.5-1.5=2$

This is a central value of an interval of width $4$, so you can achieve $2-\frac 42=0$

I don't suggest learning such a method - I am sure the use would infrequent. I would suggest noting potential computational efficiencies. Brute force can sometimes be quicker than taking the time to think.

Comment: what's the "width"?

Comment: How did you get $2-\frac{4}{2}?$

Comment: @Germania The width is $(8-6)+(2-1)+(4-3)=4$. The "central value" is at the middle of an interval of width $4$, so $\frac 42$ either side.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple: taking $x=-6, y=2, z=4$, you obtain $|x+y+z|=0$, and as an absolute value can't be negative…

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Define binary variables $u$, $v$, $w$ to indicate whether $x$, $y$, and $z$ are negative or positive, respectively.  Define variable $t$ to represent $x+y+z$.  Then the problem is to minimize $t$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
t &\ge x+y+z \\ 
t &\ge -(x+y+z) \\ 
-8u+ 6(1-u) \le x &\le -6u+ 8(1-u) \\
-2v+ 1(1-v) \le y &\le -1v+ 2(1-v) \\
-4w+ 3(1-w) \le z &\le -3w+ 4(1-w) \\
u,v,w &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking endpoints. This means a total of $4^n$ triples to check where $n$ is the number of constraints of the type you've specified. This isn't too bad for a small number of constraints. Perhaps just by good luck, but I did this quickly in my head. $x=6$, $y=-2$, and $z=-4$ implies $|x+y+z|=0$, which is the minimum that the absolute value of anything can be.

If the question is to generalize this to arbitrarily many constraints then the questions becomes more subtle.

Comment: How did you get $4^n$ triples?

Comment: Right, if we have only the constrain $6 \leq |x| \leq 8$ then the border of the feasible region consists of $4$ points, $\{-8,-6,6,8\}$. Adding the constraint $1 \leq |y| \leq 2$, there are $4^2$ pairs in the border of the feasible region, specifically the Cartesian product $\{-8,-6,6,8\} \times \{-1,-1,1,2\}$. So on. So, really, I should've said $4^n$ $n$-tuples.

Comment: Note also that the absolute function IS differentiable anywhere besides zero. So, you can use the typical approach for constrained optimization. Differentiate. Check critical points (if there are any; in this case we know there won't be, since the derivative of the absolute value function is nowhere equal to zero, so we can just skip this step). Check end points of the feasible region.

Comment: I suppose ideally you should check more than just the very corners, but its as a good a place to start as any.